# After something (is done/has been done) something else (will) happen

Tags: time-reference

Which of these sentences are grammatically correct?

> 1. After this code is compiled you get the next HTML.
> 2. After this code is compiled you will get the next HTML.
> 3. After this code has been compiled you get the next HTML.
> 4. After this code has been compiled you will get the next HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All four of your statements are grammatically correct.

Whether you prefer to say **is compiled** or **has been compiled** makes no difference. They amount to the same thing.

Whether you prefer **....get the next...** or **...will get the next....** is also a matter of choice but with this consideration.

If I were making a statement of fact, I would omit **will**:

> If you do this, you get that result

But if I were writing to clients to inform them of some development, I would prefer to include **will**.

> If you open the attached file, you will find the information you requested.

At the end of the day, the choice is just a question of nuance.

Comment: Are there situations where native speakers prefer to use the present perfect tense?

Comment: Sorry for the meticulousness, it's just hard to imagine that there is not even a hint of difference.

Comment: The difference is that the first is a bland statement of fact, the second is worded politely to a personal contact. The meaning is the same. It's the difference between asking **will you pass me the salt** and **would you pass me the salt**. The latter shows a greater degree of civility..

Comment: I meant *present perfect* vs *present* but you've already said that they are the same. Thanks to your explanation, a lot has become clear to me.